# postgresql: how to store id in session

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres, adminer

I'm using postgreSQL with Python (using Flask and SQLAlchemy as ORM), and I am implementing a website which requires the user to register and log in, after registering I want the user to automatically log in, for this I used:

```
# storing id in session  
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username ",
{"username": request.form.get("username")})
    session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

# Redirect user to home page
    return redirect("/")
```

but it gives a error like:

```
TypeError: 'ResultProxy' object does not support indexing
```

So I am stuck how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you should call `fetchall` or `fetchone` method on the result proxy:

```
rows = db.execute('query').fetchall()
session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
```